# Sort single column numpy arrays using another numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

Consider that I load columns from a text file using:

```
x, y, z = np.loadtxt(myfile, unpack=True)
```

What would be the syntax to sort `x`, `y` and `z` by increasing values of `x` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

```
argsortx = np.argsort(x)
x, y, z = x[argsortx], y[argsortx], z[argsortx]
```